# ThreeJS: Simple City Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, gis, qgis

**Problem:**
I have encountered major issues with performance with regard to a scene rendered with *Three JS*. The problem concerns *rendering a large number of simple geometries* (11,107). 
(edit)
Each building has a unique height based on elevation data, a unique shape based on their outline, and a material of 5 possible options depending on the size of the area they take up.

I have **isolated the issue in the first scene below**, the second link provides context. Turning off the polygon buildings in the second link illustrates the drop in framerate that the layer is causing.

[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvPya.jpg)

- [View 3JS Render (Polygons Only)](https://alanscandrett.github.io/profile/portfolio/misc/1_Hour_Map/polygons_only/wai_lowspec.html)
- [View Entire Scene](https://alanscandrett.github.io/profile/portfolio/misc/1_Hour_Map/3gis_lowspec_test/wai_lowspec.html)

**How polygon attributes were determined:**

> Each polygon has a *uniform height*, but *unique shape based upon a building footprint*. Furthermore, *each building is assigned a colour  from a gradient relative to the size of its area* (large yellow, mid red small purple). As a reference, this was achieved in a geographic information system before being passed to ThreeJS (QGIS, with QGIStoTHREEJS plugin).

**Attempted Solutions:**
I have focused on trying to merge the polygons geometry to reduce the number of render calls. However, because each polygon has an assigned colour I have faced issues applying the appropriate materials and mesh. I am struggling with the logic of how to do this in context of the two loops in operation.

**Relevant Code Snippet:**
The full source can be found [here](https://github.com/alanscandrett/profile/blob/master/portfolio/misc/1_Hour_Map/polygons_only/Qgis2threejs.js), and a download of the working code is available [here](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/alanscandrett/profile/tree/master/portfolio/misc/1_Hour_Map/polygons_only). This snippet is from lines 1935 to 1987.

 I have trimmed the ThreeJS source to what is relevant to my issue.

```
    ///////////////// WIP /////////////////
Q3D.PolygonLayer.prototype.build = function(parent) {
    var materials = this.materials,
        project = this.project;

    if (this.objType == "Extruded") {


        // (3) Function for creating the individual building polygons 
        var createSubObject = function(f, polygon, z) {
            var shape = new THREE.Shape(Q3D.Utils.arrayToVec2Array(polygon[0]));
            for (var i = 1, l = polygon.length; i < l; i++) {
                shape.holes.push(new THREE.Path(Q3D.Utils.arrayToVec2Array(polygon[i])));
            }

            // Where the problems start...

            // Here each geometry is created turned into a mesh with its unqiue material
            var geom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
                bevelEnabled: false,
                amount: f.h
            });
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, materials[f.m].m);
            mesh.position.z = z;
            return mesh;

            //I am not sure how I can merge each polygons geometry with the others whilst allowing each polygon to hold onto its unique colouring...

        };

        // (2) Function for creating polygon layer
        var createObject = function(f) {
            if (f.polygons.length == 1) { // TRUE for building polygons
                return createSubObject(f, f.polygons[0], f.zs[0]); // calls function to create each building

            }
        };
    }


    // (1) function for manufacturing each layer
    this.f.forEach(function(f, fid) {
        f.objs = []; // create array of objects
        var obj = createObject(f); // call polygon creation method
        obj.userData.layerId = this.index;
        obj.userData.featureId = fid;
        this.addObject(obj);
        f.objs.push(obj);
    }, this);

    if (parent) parent.add(this.objectGroup);
};

///////////////// END OF WIP /////////////////
```

Edit: The structure of each geometry is as follows(f).

> **GEOMETRY** 
>   **f**[**A**] = {**h**, **m**, **polygons**, **zs**}; 
>   Given that **f** is one of the 11,000 geometries, **A** is an index (0 to 1106), **h** is a float, **m** is an int (0 to 5) that acts as an index for accessing one of the five colour categories, **polygons** is a list of coordinate for building footprint edges, and **zs** is the extrusion height.
>
> e.g. 
>   f[11106] = {h:0.0302738130622,m:1,polygons:[[[[-23.0863540568,-1.57556646762],[-23.1968547585,-1.56551240558],[-23.1928481251,-1.49924919288],[-23.0803253841,-1.50930323633],[-23.0863540568,-1.57556646762]]]],zs:[0.0695352124961]};
>
> **MATERIAL** 
>   There are five colour categories. the **index** acts as a reference for a given geometry to find its associated material.
>
> e.g.
>   f[11106].m points to 
>   **m**[**1**] = {c:0xcb4778,type:0};

**There must be someone who knows a way of rendering these buildings without hammering out so many draw calls** . Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: you have 11,000 (11,107) geometries, not 11,000 polygons

Comment: Modified the question text, thanks for the correction 2pha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding thousands of extruded meshes to your scene and this is resulting in performance issues due to too many draw calls.

One solution is to create a single mesh, which will result in a single draw call. You can use `ExtrudeGeometry` to do this, but `ExtrudeBufferGeometry` is more efficient.

```
var shapes = [];
shapes.push( shape_1 );
...
shapes.push( shape_n );

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shapes, extrudeSettings );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( mesh );
```

If you need to apply different colors to the shapes, one option is to add vertex colors to your geometry. Another option, if there are not too many different colors, is add `groups` to your geometry. Which one is best depends on your use case.

EDIT: Actually, in your case, it may be easiest to just have a separate extruded mesh for each color.

EDIT: [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6vuxvr8/) that shows how to populate a single `BufferGeometry` with various extruded shapes.

three.js r.89

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, however I am struggling to implement the separate extruded mesh. I may just be way out of my depth here as I cannot figure out how to alter the series of functions correctly.

Comment: You thought about what I wrote for less than 13 minutes. :/   Practice the code pattern I proposed with https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html.

Comment: Its not that I didn't fully appreciate your advice @WestLangley, but more that I am too unsure of how a mesh works. As each geometry item appears to have a unique `f.zs[0]`, which I think is the mesh height, I am not sure how to reconcile that with having a single mesh for all polygons of the same colour.

I am quite confused as to how to account for the differing mesh heights using a monolithic mesh for a colour, e.g. yellow.

Comment: To add with a [poorly drawn diagram](http://iforce.co.nz/i/hnr21mpt.kkt.jpg), I need to be able to give the mesh an elevation (red) relative to sea level (black) alongside the geometric dimensions (blue). A monolithic mesh for each colour prevents that from what I am reading, is there an alternative to this?

Comment: To expand on this a bit more, if I can somehow set the position of the ExtrudeGeometry (e.g. with translate(x,y,z)) before having to do so with the mesh, I think I could then leverage the idea of a mesh per colour.

Comment: Hmm... Unique elevation and different extrusion amount for each extruded shape. Then my answer is too restrictive... This can be done... it will just take some work...

Comment: A mesh per color should work as long as the color groups are not going to change.

Comment: I have been experimenting with setting the geometry position instead of the mesh position, [but am not getting very far](http://iforce.co.nz/i/exduemee.ihy.jpg). Is it sensible of me to try do so @West? I cannot find a way of translating an extruded geometry. [The ThreeJS source code for the function ExtrudeGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry.js) function imports Geometry and BufferGeometry [translate](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry.translate), but it seems I cannot leverage that (not sure if I get inheritance properly).

Comment: Check out the fiddle I added to my answer. I think it shows you how to do everything you need...

Comment: I just wanted to thank you a lot for taking the time to walk me through this, I managed to get a single mesh in at last. Now it will just be ensuring the elevation per building is applied, and the colour scheme sorted! Once thats done I'll update the question with the working code. I really appreciate it! [preview](http://iforce.co.nz/i/kfdqzeks.fwr.jpg)